# In Bazel, is there a way to programmatically set host_cpu / host_platform based on the commandline choice of cpu / platform?

Tags: bazel

I've got a project which contains binaries targeting a number of architectures. Toolchain for each of those architectures is each paired with slightly different version of a host toolchain.

At this point the users need to manually specify the --host_cpu along with --cpu flag, but the host_cpu can always be starightforwardly derived from the value of the cpu.

Is the a way to acomplish that at the BUILD file/Starlark level?

EDIT:
I may have stated the issue too broadly, when my question is very narrow: is there a way to make the two bazel invocations below equivalent by means putting code in WORKSPACE/BUILD/.bzl file that will internally edit the value of the host_cpu flag to be equal to the value computed based on the value of cpu flag.

```
bazel build --cpu=CPU_A --host_cpu=HOST_CPU_A
```

equivalent to

```
bazel build --cpu=CPU_A
```

and

```
bazel build --cpu=CPU_B --host_cpu=HOST_CPU_B
```

equivalent to

```
bazel build --cpu=CPU_B
```

I know that there may be workarounds and alternative solutions, but I'm trying to determine if this narrow question has a positive answer.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about your toolchains? In particular: are you using platforms, and why are the host CPUs different if they all run on the same host?

Comment: @BrianSilverman thank you for commenting. I've expanded the question a little bit I'm a bit hesitant to go into the details of the setup due to workplace confidentiality requirements. Like I wrote in the edit, I know there may be alternative aproaches, but I'm looking for information about feasibility of this particular one.